# Robust method to find vertical lines in image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Consider the following images with vertical grid lines.

[image]

They can be loaded in mathematica by the following code:

```
path="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ccosnett/epc_parser/master/assets/bestiary/";
imgs = path <> # & /@ {
                        "102489965-2-ei-rating.png"
                      , "102492044-1-epc.jpg"
                      , "102519884-1-epc-graphs.jpg"
                      , "102729176-2-eir.jpeg"
                      , "102984668-1-epc-rating-graph.png"
                      , "103003823-1-epc.gif"
                      , "103187228-4-epc-rating-graph.png"
                      , "103309151-1-ee-rating.png"
                      , "105825026-1-epc-1.png"
                      , "105825038-1-epc-1.jpeg"
                      , "105829613-1-epc-1.png"
                      , "105835280-1-epc-1.jpeg"
                      , "108300254-1-epc-rating-graph.png"
                      , "108386993-1-environment-impact.jpg"
                      , "108386993-2-energy-efficiency.jpg"
                      , "test-1-12.png"
                      , "test-81-29.png"
                      , "test-88-1.png"};
images = Import /@ imgs
```

## Challenge:

write a function which returns the vertical grid lines on the right hand side of the images.

[image]

## Attempt 1:

I tried to preprocess my images to make it easier for [`ImageLines`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageLines.html). I made all the images grayscale and all the lines white on black.

```
Clear[verticalLines];
verticalLines[im_] := Module[{imag, lines, vertLines},
                              imag = ColorNegate[ColorConvert[im, "Grayscale"]];
                              lines = ImageLines[imag];
                              vertLines = Cases[lines, Line[{{x1_, _}, {x2_, _}}] /; Abs[x1 - x2 ] < 2];
                              HighlightImage[imag, vertLines ]
                      ];
verticalLines /@ images
```

[image]

Unfortunately this is not a robust method because it misses many of the vertical lines.

How can I detect vertical lines in a more robust manner?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This preprocessing seems more stable `Binarize[GaussianFilter[ColorConvert[im,"Grayscale"],1,{0,1}],0.05]`

Comment: Did you try using the second and/or third parameters of ImageLines? These provide some flexibility in what is detected.

Answer (score 1):

```
jj = Rasterize[fig, RasterSize -> 200];
kk = ImageAdjust[
   Rasterize[ImageTake[jj, {130, 245}, {60, 182}], 
    RasterSize -> 300], {.01, .01}];
ImageAdjust@
 ImageConvolve[Erosion[MorphologicalBinarize[kk, {.8, .9}], 4], 
  50 {{-2, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0,
      0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0, 0, 2}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the simplest way is to use the built-in function `ImageLines`

```
i = 4;
HighlightImage[images[[i]], ImageLines[EdgeDetect[images[[i]], 0.6], 0.4]]
```

[image]